# Scoring a dataframe based on percentile rank of value in row - Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe in python and I want to create a new column to score each row based on its percentile rank. I have tried `apply` but could not get it to work.

So fundamentally I would like to check the percentile rank for a value (.rank or .quantile), if it is in the top 20% (relative to all values in the column) allocate 100% of the points (p = 100), if it is in the top 40% get 50% (0.5 * p) of the points, else get no points (0 * p).

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Please post your code and as mentioned in [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank you. I am sorry. I read in the df from a long csv so couldn't post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a quantile to define your breaks, pd.cut to break them into the categories and then use the scores as labels:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.random.uniform(0,1,100)})
p = 100
pd.cut(df['x'],df['x'].quantile([0,0.6,0.8,1]),labels=[0,0.5*p,p])
```

Comment: Hi StupidWolf, Thank you for your reply, this formula worked! Really elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a column rank containing ranks of each row.
First initialize a column of points as 0, then assign the respective values.
**Note:** Order is important

```
df['points']=0
df.loc[df['rank']/len(df['rank'])<=0.40,'points'] = 50*p
df.loc[df['rank']/len(df['rank'])<=0.20,'points'] = 100*p
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you so much! I created a percentile column data['p'] = data['p'].rank(pct=1) and it worked with your formula.