# Python Pandas - Assign Values to Rows based on Top x% Values found in a Column

Tags: python, pandas

Take this mockup dataframe for example:

```
CustomerID   Number of Purchases

   ABC                5
   DEF               24
   GHI               85
   JKL                2
   MNO              100
```

Assume this dataframe is first sorted by **Number of Purchases** (descending).
How do I add a new column to it called **Score**, and have values assigned to it as follows:

- Out of the top 60% customers (meaning the first 3 rows after sorting), 3 should be assigned to **Score**.
- Out of the next top 20% customers (row 4 after sorting), 2 should be assigned to **Score**.
- Out of the next and last top 20% customers (row 5 after sorting), 1 should be assigned to **Score**.

How do I do this in a large dataframe?

Comment: This may help you get on the right track: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61631942/scoring-a-dataframe-based-on-percentile-rank-of-value-in-row-python

Comment: Score is the sum of the selected rows?

Comment: @inquirer No, it is a score given to where the Number of Purchases lie in a particular proportion of the whole table.

Comment: @Jiehfeng i.e. for the first three lines it is: 60%(in each line)?

Comment: @inquirer The first three lines after sorting by descending of Number of Purchases will mean that they are the top 60%, the fourth line will be the next top 20%, and the last line will be the last top 20% (60 + 20 + 20 = 100). So Lines 1-3 will have the Score column's values as 3 each, Line 4 as 2, and Line 5 as 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'CustomerID': ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL', 'MNO'],
                   'Number of Purchases': [5, 24, 85, 2, 100]})

df = df.sort_values(by=['Number of Purchases'], ascending=False)


proc = len(df) / 100
aaa = [[0, int(60 * proc), 3], [int(60 * proc), int(80 * proc), 2], [int(80 * proc), len(df), 1]]
df['Score'] = np.nan
df = df.reset_index()


for i in aaa:
    df.loc[i[0]:i[1] - 1, 'Score'] = i[2]

print(df)
```

Output

```
   index CustomerID  Number of Purchases  Score
0      4        MNO                  100    3.0
1      2        GHI                   85    3.0
2      1        DEF                   24    3.0
3      0        ABC                    5    2.0
4      3        JKL                    2    1.0
```

First comes sorting, where it is indicated: ascending=False, so that the sorting is in reverse order.
The proc variable is how many rows in 1%.

A nested list aaa is created. In which the first element is the start index, the second is the end index of the range of strings. And the third element is evaluation. A 'Score' column is created with empty values and dataframe indexes are reset.

In the loop, the rows are accessed by loc through slices (this is from which index the rows are selected). Since loc is accessed inclusively (for example, the end index is 3, then the data will be selected by index 3), so i[1] - 1 is used.

Answer (score 0):

Once the dataframe (df) has been **sorted** by `Number_of_Purchases`, 
you can generate the `Score` column by using the:

- `.rank(pct=True)` - function: which calculates the rank (percentage)
- and then **apply** a **lambda** function to convert this rank to a score.

### Code:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'CustomerID': ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL', 'MNO'],
                    'Number of Purchases': [5, 24, 85, 2, 100]})

# Sort and then create 'Score' column
df = df.sort_values(by=['Number of Purchases'], ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)

df['Score'] = df['Number of Purchases'].rank(pct=True).apply(lambda x: 1 if x<=0.2 else 2 if x<=0.4 else 3)

print(df)
```

### Output:

```
  CustomerID  Number of Purchases  Score
0        MNO                  100      3
1        GHI                   85      3
2        DEF                   24      3
3        ABC                    5      2
4        JKL                    2      1
```